# I have a list of words. I want to find a word for a fixed length

Tags: python, string, list, search

Here is my explanation:

`myList = ['Albasit', 'Nahian', 'Hi', 'Kazi', 'Zuljalal', 'Md.', 'Maslinia']`

I want to search word in the list with their length. So that I can get the word which is 4 in len.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
print([x for x in myList if len(x) == 4])
```

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, you have two options. Filtering or a simple list comprehension.

```py
myList = ['Albasit', 'Nahian', 'Hi', 'Kazi', 'Zuljalal', 'Md.', 'Maslinia']

list(filter(lambda x: len(x) == 4, myList))
# or
[x for x in myList if len(x) == 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new list filtering only the elements with `len(element) == 4`

```
myList = ['Albasit', 'Nahian', 'Hi', 'Kazi', 'Zuljalal', 'Md.', 'Maslinia']

new_list = [x for x in myList if len(x) == 4]

print(new_list)
>>> ['Kazi']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str_list = ["these", "are", "some", "random", "strings"]

for my_str in str_list:
    if len(my_str) == 3:
        print(my_str)
```

This will print out every 3 Letter word in the list. You can append these to a new list and then print the new list as well. Up to you.

Comment: Some tips: don't use types as variable names `str`, no need for extra parentheses in if-clauses, for-loops are mostly discouraged when list comprehensions are equivalent alternatives.

Comment: @BramVanroy Thanks for the tips. I warn others about using types as variable names, yet do the same mistakes. Am not very experienced with list comprehensions. Will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

```
myList = ['Albasit', 'Nahian', 'Hi', 'Kazi', 'Zuljalal', 'Md.', 'Maslinia']

res = list(filter(lambda x: len(x) == 4, myList)) 
print(res) # ['Kazi']
```

Comment: provide context to boost question quality. You're competing with 4 more for rep. EoR.